# store paragraphs in multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, textbox

I need to store a large text (which includes paragraphs) in sql server database.I am able to store it but the paragraphs and spaces are all gone when i try to retrieve it in a label somewhere.I have tried inserting '< br/ >' and '/r/n' at the end of paragraphs but they throw an error which says 'dangerous input' something.

What are my options here?

Comment: It is asp.net that prevents your "html rich" text, as it is potentially dangerous. If you trust the user that they won't do anything malicious then you can disable this per page header: ValidateRequest="false" see this : http://devtacular.com/articles/gkonrad/allowing-html-formatted-user-input-in-aspnet/

Comment: the paragraph is stored as it is in sql but it wont show up in a label. You might wanna use Literal for that and then replace \n by <br \> while displaying the text on html page as text in the sql contains \n as new line but it cannot be read.